# Typos are not seen as compilation errors in C++

Tags: c++

Would this cause a compilation error?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{clrscr();
int x=2;
switch (x)
     {case 1: cout<<"i am 1";
defult: cout<<"i made a typo";}   }
```

If not, why not?

Comment: Do you mean will misspelling `default` cause a compile-time error? And that's the weirdest brace style I've ever seen...

Comment: Compile and find out, I'd say. Could you explain why you need to ask us?

Comment: @jdv-Jan: Obviously he's on a phone or something where a compiler is not available. That's what you *have* to assume when people ask questions like this.

Comment: @Code: I was honestly curious. Rereading the question, I believe the question was what kind of errors are detected compile time, and which ones at link or runtime.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming `conio.h` and `iostream.h` exist, `cout` is defined in the global namespace and your compiler accepts the non-standard signature `void main()` for the `main` function, your code will compile without errors.

You're probably wondering why `defult:` is not an error: That is because it is interpreted as a label. I.e. your switch statement has a single case and inside that case there is a label named "defult", which you can jump to using `goto defult`.

It should be noted that after I removed the references to `conio.h` and `clrscr`, changed `iostream.h` to `iostream`, referred to `cout` as `std::cout` and changed the type of `main` to `int`, `g++ -Wall` compiled the code without errors, but produced the warning "warning: label ‘defult’ defined but not used". So while the code is indeed valid code and will compile fine, a decent compiler will warn you about the typo.

Comment: +1 for noticing `void main()`. What is that nonsense? Are there really books that teach this?

Comment: C allows a compiler to accept this, probably that's where it comes from.

Comment: @etarion: If everything the compiler "accepted" became "acceptable", the entire computer industry might collapse in on itself. When one sits down to write a book, I should hope they've at least read the spec for that language, not just hacked together some code in a random compiler.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I didn't say "a compiler accepts this", i said "C allows a compiler to accept this". C as in the ANSI C, the language specification. It (the standard) specificically says "or in some other implementation-defined manner."

Answer (score 3):

> would this cause a compilation error?

Yes! `<iostream.h>` and `<conio.h>`are non-standard headers.
Return type of `main` should be `int`.

BTW `defult :` is not really an error because it is just a label name.

Comment: Turbo C is the new old standard at SO.

Comment: I suspect your after-thought was the answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Your "defult" here is taken to be a marker, such as would be noticed in a goto statement, so this is not a compiler-error worthy situation. It's your fault, not the compilers.